# Question about set notation regarding removal of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider the sets 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} &= \{1,2,3,5,7\}\\
\mathcal{B} &= \{2,4,6,8\}\\
\mathcal{R} &= \{2,5\}
\end{align*}

I want to remove the elements in $\mathcal{R}$ from $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Does it make sense to write:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}\backslash\mathcal{R} &= \{1,3,7\}\\
\mathcal{B}\backslash\mathcal{R} &= \{4,6,8\}
\end{align*}
even though $\mathcal{B}$ does not contain element $5$? I am asking because I have multiple sets that I want to remove a set of elements from, but I do not know if the sets contain the elements to remove. I cannot think of an alternative notation.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, thank you, edited.

Comment: Yeah it's just perfect write it this way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your notation is perfect.

By definition, $X\setminus Y$ is the set of elements that belong to $X$ but not to $Y$.
It is irrelevant whether $Y$ is a subset of $X$ or not.

BTW, the correct TeX macro is `\setminus`, not `\backslash`. See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Notation).

Comment: I've always wondered: is there a historical reason (or a reason at all) to notate the subtraction of sets as $A \setminus B$ instead of just $A-B$? (Also, small edit: "Your notation" instead of "you notation")

Comment: @Miguelgondu, perhaps to avoid confusion in case subtraction makes sense for elements of $A$ and $B$. For instance, in the real line or in a vector space. But I don't know the historical reason.

Comment: I'm mostly self taught but my impression is that using the same syntax for similar concepts can be a double-edged sword. You can make a lot of accurate connections/generalizations while the analogy holds, but where it doesn't, the familiarity works against you. If I were designing the notation I might think of a few counter-intuitive examples - like 0-A=0 and A-B-B=A-B, in the spirit of this question - and pick some obscure symbol to avoid creating so many pitfalls. These days you have options - perhaps AB? AB? No?

Answer (score 1):

This notation is usually shorthand for $B\cap R^c$. So this works fine if you imagine all your sets are subsets of some common set: in this case they're all subsets of $\mathbf{N}$ the natural numbers. It's also possible to write $B\setminus (R\cap B)$ if the situation worries you.